# Viewing post while editing

Tags: plugin-recommendation

While the wordpress editor is great, it's not completely WYSIWYG. Various CSS settings from the theme aren't displayed in the editor.

Is there a plug-in that will make the editor more WYSIWYG by loading the CSS?
Even a plug-in that adds a frame in the post-edit page that shows the post being edited will be good enough. I just want to see how the post will look like without having to open multiple tabs on my browser.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 3.0 WP allows to add custom stylesheet to visual editor.

See:

- [`add_editor_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style) (documentation)
- [Style the post editor just like your theme](http://devpress.com/blog/style-the-post-editor-just-like-your-theme/) (tutorial)

Comment: That's a lot of work, and doesn't quite cut it for complex designs. I ended up adding an iframe to the edit-page showing the post/page using a meta_box.

Comment: *@OmerGertel* - Your implementation sounds interesting. Care to share with the rest of us?